# Crystal Reports won't display related table data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm new to Crystal Reports and trying to maintain someone else's code -- so bear with me.  I have a crystal report that is tied to a DataSet with 2 related DataTables.

[image]

[image]

I'm grouping by `JurorProfile.JurorPK`.  In my Group Header, I display information from the JurorProfile DataTable.

In the report detail, I have RowNumber, `JurorQuestionAnswers.Question` and `JurorQuestionAnswers.Answer`.

In my c# code, I'm populating the data like this:

```cs
public void SetDataSource(AdoProvider provider, int sessionPK, int jurorPK)
{
   string commandText;
   AdoQuery query;

   commandText = $@"select j.* from Juror j
   where j.JurorPK in (select JurorFK from SessionJurorLink where SessionFK = @sessionId)
   {(jurorPK > 0 ? " and jurorPK = @jurorId" ? "")}
   ";
   query = provider.CreateQuery(commandText, null
      , provider.CreateParameter("sessionId", DbType.Int32)
      , provider.CreateParameter("jurorId", DbType.Int32)
   );
   AdoReader jReader = query.ExecuteReader(sessionPK, jurorPK);
   report.Database.Tables["JurorProfile"]
     .SetDataSource((IDataReader)jReader.DataReader);

   commandText = $@"select ... from JurorAnswers ...
   where sessionFK = @sessionId
   {(jurorPK > 0 ? " and jurorFK = @jurorId " : "")}
   order by JurorFK, Rank, ParentFK, QuestionPK
   ";
   query = provider.CreateQuery(commandText, null
      , provider.CreateParameter("sessionId", DbType.Int32)
      , provider.CreateParameter("jurorId", DbType.Int32)
   );
   AdoReader qaReader = query.ExecuteReader(sessionPK, jurorPK);
   report.Database.Tables["JurorQuestionAnswers"]
     .SetDataSource((IDataReader)qaReader.DataReader);
}
```

However, when my report runs, the Group Heading displays and I get a record number printed for each question but the Question and Answer are not displayed.

[image]

It would appear, that Crystal Reports is not mapping the data results from my second query to the DataTable.

What's even weirder is that `JurorQuestionAnswers` DataTable currently has a redundant Lastname and Firstname field.  If I include those fields in the detail area (`JurorQuestionAnswers.Lastname`, `JurorQuestionAnswers.Firstname`), they actually show up -- the data was properly mapped.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update - Image of Links Tab**

[image]

Comment: If you inspect the content of report.Database, can you see that the data is really there? I notice you use two different names: JurorAnswers and JurorQuestionAnswers, but I think it is ok - but you want to check if those names must be the same... Third and last, check if you are linking the tables in crystal, in the tab "Link" that is displayed in the second image (this is not THE problem, but it can be ONE problem later).

Comment: If I add code to loop through the reader values -- yes, the data is there in the reader.  I tried inspecting the content of report.Database.  It definitely shows both tables as well as the link between them but I wasn't able to find any kind of property that held data -- for either table.

Comment: Try to inspect the dataset using: dataset.WriteXml(...)

Comment: Just to anticipate some thoughts to follow: I'm thinking in these possibilities: (1) the data is not there; (2) the names of columns and tables or types in the dataset are different from those defined for the rpt (do you use XSD file?); (3) something is suppressing the "invisible" fields (did you use the suppress formula?).

Comment: I remembered one more thing: may you show the tab "Links" of your "Database Expert"? And what happens when you use the "preview" feature?

Comment: I added the image of the Link tab above.  When I use preview, it just shows the report with a bunch of "bogus" data -- not sure where it gets that from -- guessing VS is just making up some data to show.  Until runtime - there really is no data source for the dataset.  The data source is being added by the code above.

Comment: In regards to your previous question. 1) The data is there in the reader.  (Couldn't find a way to access the DataSet itself -- it does not seem to exist as a property of the report. 2) The names are all the same -- in fact, if I remove the grouping and comment out the JurorProfile datatable and simply populate the JurorQA datatable, everything works fine. 3) No suppression of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work.  Basically, it involved replacing the DataSet that existed on the report with a new DataSet.

I had to change my code as follows:

```cs
public void SetDataSource(AdoProvider provider, int sessionPK, int jurorPK)
{
   string commandText;
   AdoQuery query;
   
   // ** Added Direct Reference to DataSet **//
   var ds = new QuestionAnswersData(); 

   commandText = $@"select j.* from Juror j
   where j.JurorPK in (select JurorFK from SessionJurorLink where SessionFK = @sessionId)
   {(jurorPK > 0 ? " and jurorPK = @jurorId" ? "")}
   ";
   query = provider.CreateQuery(commandText, null
      , provider.CreateParameter("sessionId", DbType.Int32)
      , provider.CreateParameter("jurorId", DbType.Int32)
   );
   AdoReader jReader = query.ExecuteReader(sessionPK, jurorPK);

   // ** REPLACED THIS LINE **//
   // report.Database.Tables["JurorProfile"]
   //  .SetDataSource((IDataReader)jReader.DataReader); 

   //** WITH THIS LINE **//
   ds.Tables["JurorProfile"].Load((IDataReader)jReader.DataReader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, null);  

   commandText = $@"select ... from JurorAnswers ...
   where sessionFK = @sessionId
   {(jurorPK > 0 ? " and jurorFK = @jurorId " : "")}
   order by JurorFK, Rank, ParentFK, QuestionPK
   ";
   query = provider.CreateQuery(commandText, null
      , provider.CreateParameter("sessionId", DbType.Int32)
      , provider.CreateParameter("jurorId", DbType.Int32)
   );
   AdoReader qaReader = query.ExecuteReader(sessionPK, jurorPK);

   //** REPLACED THIS LINE **//
   //report.Database.Tables["JurorQuestionAnswers"]
   // .SetDataSource((IDataReader)qaReader.DataReader); 

   //** WITH THIS LINE **//
   ds.Tables["JurorQuestionAnswers"].Load((IDataReader}jReader.DataReader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, null);

   //** NOW TIE THE DATASOURCE DIRECTLY TO THE REPORT **//
   base.SetDataSource(ds); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say *"`JurorQuestionAnswers` DataTable currently has a redundant Lastname and Firstname field"* I'm curious to know if, when you click on them in the dataset designer and look in the `Expression` property, you see something like `Parent.Firstname` (or whether the code contains anything like `somedatatable.FirstnameColumn.Expression = "Parent.Firstname"`).

It's been a long time since I used CR, but my instant assumption is that CR cannot navigate DataRelations and someone worked this out and instead used the [built in ability for a DataColumn Expression to reference other tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netcore-3.1#parentchild-relation-referencing) to conceptually import the parent data into the child table so that CR only has one table of data to deal with. CR will then preform a group on the parent columns itself (and because they reliably repeat the same data they group down to just one value) so you achieve the same effect, you just had to repeat the data

If this is the case, follow the pattern - if you want parent column X in the header, add a datacolumn (in the designer) to the child table, called ParentX (I like to put the word Parent in columns that are derived by relation, so people don't assume theyre redundant, but delberate), set its Experssion to `Parent.X` and then update/refresh your CR so it sees the new column and group on it

Comment: Unfortunately, `Expression` is empty on both `Lastname` and `Firstname`.  Additionally, what's weird is that CR does seem to be navigating DataRelations in that it is finding the appropriate number of child records and iterating through the appropriate number of detail rows -- just not able to produce the actual data.